# Can recursion be used to guarantee an object gets saved to the DB in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

I am making payouts to my sub-merchants and wanted to know if I could use recursion to guarantee that when a payout is made to them, we save that data to our DB.

**Example:**

```
def make_payout
  result = object.process_payout_through_gateway
  if result.success?
    payout = Payout.new
    payout[:paid] = true
    save_payout(payout)
  end
end

def save_payout(payout)
  begin
    payout.save!
  rescue e
    save_payout(payout)
  end
end
```

Comment: So your "error handling" is just retrying the same thing over and over until you get a stack overflow?

Comment: Ahh I see, that would definitely cause a loop. It would be better to log the error and handle it from there, correct?

Comment: Stack level too deep?

Comment: Well it depends on the nature of the error, and the nature of what you're trying to do. You'll probably want some kind of retry strategy (e.g. try in 1s, then again in 5s, then again in 10s, if that fails, give up and handle the error)

Comment: I mean, if you want to save it regardless, you could `payout.save(validate: false)` but, like alexander said, it just depends on what you are trying to do here...

Comment: Using a backoff library to retry at a given interval and then finally to give up is not a bad idea - https://github.com/ooyala/retries

Answer (score 2):

If you want to gaunrentee it gets saved without validating the object:

`payout.save(validate: false)`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**. Unless the error is transient, retrying the save operation over and over again will not help you and in some cases it could even exacerbate the problem.

If you expect certain errors to *routinely* occur during *normal* operation, you can choose to *selectively* handle those errors by retrying the operation, for example. The keyword here is *selectiveness* - if you blindly `rescue` everything, you risk retrying the operation even when the error is caused by something you cannot routinely recover from, like a programming bug. Therefore, you should always specify a specific exception class that you would like to `rescue`:

```
begin
  payout.save!
rescue ExceptionThatHappensSometimesButIsNoBigDeal
  # ignore error + maybe log it, etc.
end
```

Catching certain exceptions and retrying the operation later is a strategy frequently used when talking to non-critical external APIs, since those can have transient outages at any time. If you don't ignore these non-critical exceptions, they bubble up and bring down your app with them as well.

However, retrying failed operations that only touch systems which you have control over (such as saving to the local database) is usually counterproductive - if you silently ignore these errors, you risk not finding out about them in time.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys, all great answers. I personally went with:

```
def save_payout(payout)
  begin
    payout.save!
  rescue e
    puts "Payment to User-ID: #{current_user.id} FAILED TO SAVE! #{e}"
    UserMailer.send_payout_failure_email(current_user.id).deliver_now
  end
end
```

I won't mark a "right" answer and just let everyone up-vote their favorite route.

Comment: technically i did answer your question though... validating false will save it regardless if it is valid or not... you didn't really give us much information to go off of.  What you are doing there is not actually saving the record...